# Pass Data From Input Form on One Page To a Select Form on Another page?

Tags: php

There are so many examples of passing data from one page to another using `GET` and `POST` in PHP.

However what I am trying to do is a bit different.

Here is what i need to do:

I have an input textfield on one page (page1.php) and I need to pass its value/data to a Select form on another page (page2.php).

I have this on page1.php:

```
<form method="post" action="../page2.php">
  <input type="text"/>
  <button name="location" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

And I have this on page2.php:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" class="myForm" method="post" action="page2.php">
  <select style="font-size:9px;" name="timezone2" id="timezone2">

<option value="<?php echo $_GET["location"]; ?>"> </option>

</select>
</form>
```

when i run the page1.php from a browser, it will point me to the page2.php as it should but it will not show the Data/Value that was input in the  textfield `name="location"` !

First off, is what I am trying to do possible?

and if so, could someone please point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variables via GET and POST.  To pass variables to a page via GET, call the page like so:

```
/myPage.php?myParam=1
```

Then, you could run the following PHP:

```
<?php echo $_GET['myParam']; ?>
```

Which would output "1."

To pass variables via POST, post your data to the page like so:

```
<form action="myPage.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="myInput" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then, on myPage.php you could run the following:

```
<?php echo $_POST['myInput']; ?>
```

Which would output whatever was contained in the textbox before you clicked submit.

**Edit:**

It looks like you are trying to submit data from one page and have that appear in the next page as an option in your select menu.  Try this on page1.php:

```
<form method="post" action="../page2.php">
  <input type="text" name="location" value="THIS WILL APPEAR IN THE SELECT MENU AS AN OPTION"/>
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Try this on page2.php:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" class="myForm" method="post" action="page2.php">
  <select style="font-size:9px;" name="timezone2" id="timezone2">

<option value="<?php echo $_POST["location"]; ?>"><?php echo $_POST["location"]; ?></option>

</select>
</form>
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, This will only work with two input textfields on two different pages. what I am trying to do is to pass the data from one input textfield on one page to a Select/option on another page! same as my example.

Comment: No, Unfortunately that doesn't work. I have already tried that.

Comment: IF that doesn't work then you have a problem elsewhere.  This is how it's supposed to work.  The code you posted in your original question was `$_GET["location"]` whereas I have used `$_POST["location"]`

Comment: Okay, I have even changed the `$_GET["location"]` to `$_POST["location"]` but still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you are right... the problem must be from else where because I have tried it on two Fresh php pages and it did work! time to dig into the code.

Comment: Good job, that's what I would have done (isolate the issue).  Good luck finding your problem.